# Instance methods missing from prototype object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

When declaring a class (using the ECMAScript 2015 `class`) syntax, where are the methods that are defined as part of the class stored? I was expecting to find them on the prototype-object, but for some reason I could not access them in the following sample:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.a = function() {return ("a");};
  }

  b() { return ("b"); }
}

MyClass.prototype.c = function() { return ("c"); }

const m = new MyClass();

// Sanity check: All three functions are callable and return correct results
console.log(m.a()); // "a"
console.log(m.b()); // "b"
console.log(m.c()); // "c"

// Expected: The only property of the object m itself is a
console.log(Object.keys(m)); // ["a"]

// Unexpected: Where is b?
console.log(Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(m))); // ["c"]
console.log(Object.keys(MyClass.prototype)); // ["c"]
```

The `b`-function must be somewhere (it is clearly callable), but where? I tested this behavior `node 9.5.0` and `Firefox 58.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` only shows enumerable properties. The properties defined on the prototype by `class` aren’t enumerable.

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(m)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Class methods defined within the `class` syntax are *non-enumerable*, which is why `b` doesn't appear in the output of `Object.keys`:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyClass.prototype, "b")
{value: ƒ, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}

> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyClass.prototype, "c")
{value: ƒ, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**getOwnPropertyNames()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) method to return all the properties:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.a = function() {
      return ("a");
    };
  }

  b() {
    return ("b");
  }
}

MyClass.prototype.c = function() {
  return ("c");
}

const m = new MyClass();

// Sanity check: All three functions are callable and return correct results
console.log(m.a()); // "a"
console.log(m.b()); // "b"
console.log(m.c()); // "c"

// Expected: The only property of the object m itself is a
console.log(Object.keys(m)); // ["a"]

// Unexpected: Where is b?
console.log(Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(m))); // ["c"]
console.log(Object.keys(MyClass.prototype)); // ["c"]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass.prototype));
```

> The **Object.getOwnPropertyNames()** method returns an array of all properties (**including non-enumerable properties** except for those which use Symbol) found directly upon a given object.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to know _how_ to show `b`, he just wants to know _why_ it doesn't appear.

Comment: @Alnitak, at the end of the runnable snippet I've added a quote from the MDN site, and highlighted the parts related to the user question. I don't think I can be more clearer than the actual docs.